# How to do “broken stick linear regression” in R?

Tags: r, regression, change-point

I am trying to do break stick linear regression to do two things,

1) calculate the rate of phosphorus needed to ahieve maximum yeild (critical value (CV)) for 4 different cultivars of clover

2) determine statistically if the CV differ between cultivars.

Here is a published example of what I am try to do....

[image: example graph]

and here are the methods of that example....

"Shoot dry matter at 250 mg P kg−1 was assumed to
represent the maximum growth of the cultivars based on
previous experience growing T. subterraneum in this
soil (Haling et al. 2016a). The intersection of maximum
shoot yield and the linear response to P-application rates
between 10 and 80 mg P kg−1 soil was considered to
represent the critical external requirement for P. This
was analysed by means of a broken stick linear regression
with the ‘right side’ regression forced to be a
horizontal line (Eq. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUXOY.png))

[image: equation 2]

Where y is the shoot dry mass, x is the P application,
k is the maximum shoot dry mass, c is shoot dry mass at
0 mg P kg−1 and m is the gradient.
The Breakpoint of the broken stick model (i.e. the
critical P requirement) has a distribution which is approximately
an F distribution on 1 and n-3 degrees of
freedom. Utilising this, error estimates and confidence
intervals for the Breakpoint were formed and generated
in R2LINES. To test whether the breakpoints were pairwise
significantly different, a difference of unpaired
means t test was used."

Here is my attempt at this. I have made a rough and ready graph that calculates the critical value, i.e phosphorus applied to achieve maximum yield.

[image: Critical value of one culitvar]

So this graph is just of one cultivar. There is a regression line for the first 4 points, a vertical line running from maximum growth, and the intersection of these two lines is the 'critical value'. However, this is a little crude and does not achieve what I ultimately need.

Here is my data...

```
structure(list(cultivar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Dinninup", 
"Riverina", "Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35), shoot = c(1.24, 1.12, 1.28, 1.28, 1.37, 
1.4, 1.39, 1.34, 1.34, 1.53, 1.25, 1.4, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.71, 
1.52, 1.75, 1.63, 1.7, 1.23, 1.22, 1.26, 0.89, 1.2, 1.55, 1.4, 
1.19, 1.75, 1.92, 1.63, 1.64, 1.34, 1.54, 1.66, 1.88, 1.9, 2.18, 
2.03, 1.68, 0.9, 1.49, 1.41, 1.57, 0.94, 1.83, 1.6, NA, 1.98, 
2.04, 1.64, 1.71, 1.97, 1.97, 1.87, 2.21, 2.1, 2.25, 2.1, 2.24, 
1.23, 1.32, 1.47, 1.54, 1.38, 1.09, 1.41, NA, 1.23, 1.14, 1.63, 
1.61, 1.42, 1.12, 1.74, 1.89, 1.4, 1.58, 1.71, 1.64)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L))
```

Can anyone please show me how I can do the desired analysis to emulate the published example above???

Based on your advice, I was able to graph it in ggplot.....

```
fit1 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
                data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Yarloop"),
                start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
    mm1 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(yar$P), length.out = 100))
    mm1$shoot <- predict(fit1, newdata = mm1)

    fit2 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
                data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Dinninup"),
                start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
    mm2 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(din$P), length.out = 100))
    mm2$shoot <- predict(fit2, newdata = mm2)

    fit3 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
                data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Riverina"),
                start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
    mm3 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(riv$P), length.out = 100))
    mm3$shoot <- predict(fit3, newdata = mm3)

    fit4 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
                data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Seaton Park"),
                start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
    mm4 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(seat$P), length.out = 100))
    mm4$shoot <- predict(fit4, newdata = mm4)

    tgq <- summarySE(isosub, measurevar="shoot", 
    groupvars=c("P","cultivar"),na.rm = TRUE)
    ggplot(tgq, aes(x = P, y = shoot)) +
      geom_point(aes(shape=cultivar,colour=cultivar),size=4)+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
      "#D55E00"))+
      theme_bw()+
      geom_line(data = mm1, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "#D55E00")+
      geom_line(data = mm2, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "#009E73")+
      geom_line(data = mm3, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "#F0E442")+
      geom_line(data = mm4, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "#0072B2")
```

[image: ggplot of broken stick model]

This code you gave gives us the y value for the break point right?

```
coef(fit1)[["c"]] + coef(fit1)[["m"]] * coef(fit1)[["bp"]]
```

How do we do something similar to get the x value for the break point, as that is the "critical value' we neeed?

### First we fit a simple nls model to get decent starting values:

```
fit1 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
        data = isosub,
        start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
```

library(nlme)

### Then we fit the same model with the gnls function:

```
fita <- gnls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
         data = isosub, 
         params = c+ m +bp ~ 1, start = as.list(coef(fit1)), na.action = 
na.omit)
```

### Now, we stratify bp by cultivar:

```
fitb <- gnls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
         data = isosub, 
         params = list(bp ~ cultivar,c+ m +bp ~ 1), start = c(coef(fit1)[1], 
0, 0, 0, coef(fit1)[2]), 
         na.action = na.omit)
```

### If you are interested in pairwise comparisons, do the last fit using subsets of two cultivars from your data:

```
  fitab <- gnls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), data = 
isosub[isosub$cultivar %in% c("Dinninup", "Yarloop"),], 
            params = list(bp ~ cultivar), start = c(coef(fit1)[1], 0, 
coef(fit1)[2], 0), 
            na.action = na.omit)
summary(fitab)$tTable
```

I am trying to create a break stick model with this data....

```
structure(list(pot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 140L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Seaton 
Park", 
"Dinninup", "Yarloop", "Riverina"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = 
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Non- 
waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35
), form = c(1.65, 0.61, 0.47, 0.57, 0.52, 0.61, 0.48, 0.8, 0.69, 
0.63, 0.39, 0.68, 0.66, 0.51, 0.4, 0.55, 0.45, 0.41, 0.47, 0.54, 
1.7, 1.78, 1.6, 2.34, 1.52, 1.88, 1.67, 1.7, 1.88, 1.59, 1.97, 
1.6, 1.97, 2.13, 1.52, 2.5, 1.88, 1.61, 1.61, 1.65, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.02, 0.05, 0.31, 0, 0.07, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 
0, 0.03, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.12, 0.1, 0.13, 0.05, 
0.07, 0.06, 0.09, 0.05, 0.12, 0.05, 0.1, 0.06, 0.05, 0.06), G = c(0.4, 
0.23, 0.19, 0.12, 0.26, 0.25, 0.19, 0.23, 0.25, 0.4, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.39, 0.38, 0.21, 0.22, 0.28, 0.28, 0.25, 0.28, 1.02, 0.67, 0.8, 
0.78, 0.76, 0.66, 0.79, 0.81, 0.94, 0.61, 0.74, 0.64, 0.99, 0.85, 
0.86, 1, 0.86, 0.75, 0.91, 0.66, 0.91, 0.42, 0.43, 1.02, 1.48, 
0.53, 0.89, 0.7, 0.59, 0.61, 0.42, 1.04, 0.75, 0.59, 0.52, 0.84, 
0.43, 0.53, 0.66, 0.35, 0.19, 0.31, 0.21, 0.27, 0.25, 0.31, 0.21, 
0.28, 0.1, 0.29, 0.09, 0.27, 0.2, 0.19, 0.21, 0.24, 0.11, 0), 
 BA = c(1.61, 1.17, 0.94, 0.98, 1.25, 1.27, 1.15, 1.31, 1.23, 
1.42, 0.91, 1.25, 1.43, 1.61, 1.07, 1.32, 1.48, 1.38, 1.25, 
1.48, 0.09, 0.19, 0.2, 0.16, 0.1, 0.19, 0.13, 0.21, 0.14, 
0.16, 0.2, 0.14, 0.2, 0.21, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.16, 
0.17, 0.23, 0.1, 0.21, 0.27, 0.35, 0.1, 0.31, 0.29, 0.32, 
0.14, 0.21, 0.36, 0.38, 0.16, 0.31, 0.32, 0.21, 0.12, 0.33, 
3.49, 2.53, 2.34, 2.5, 3.54, 2.76, 1.56, 3.13, 2.63, 1.48, 
1.58, 2.34, 2.68, 2.96, 1.31, 3.54, 2.18, 1.5, 1.17), total = c(3.66, 
2.02, 1.59, 1.67, 2.03, 2.13, 1.83, 2.34, 2.17, 2.44, 1.49, 
2.19, 2.48, 2.49, 1.69, 2.1, 2.22, 2.07, 1.97, 2.3, 2.81, 
2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 2.95, 2.36, 2.91, 
2.38, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 3.71, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 1.19, 
0.57, 0.66, 1.34, 2.14, 0.63, 1.27, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 
1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.16, 0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 3.88, 2.79, 
2.73, 2.77, 3.86, 3.13, 1.97, 3.46, 2.95, 1.65, 1.94, 2.53, 
3, 3.28, 1.55, 3.85, 2.48, 1.66, 1.23), F2 = c(1.97, 2.21, 
1.25, 1.53, NA, 1.27, 0.78, 0.66, 1.21, 1.8, 1.36, 1.61, 
0.71, 0.14, 2.01, 1.29, 1.18, 0.97, 0.55, 1.1, 2.76, 2.34, 
2.43, 1.81, 1.7, 1.44, 1.88, 1.65, 2.34, 0.88, 1.95, 1.88, 
2.01, 1.33, 1.88, 2.02, 3.61, 1.44, 2.08, 2.01, 0.18, 0.16, 
0.15, 0.49, 0.1, 0.3, 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.03, 0.07, 0.24, 
0.16, 0.04, 0.09, 0.08, 0.09, 0.26, 0.09, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.16, NA, 0.17, 0.35, 0.25, 0.11, 0.1, 0.02, 0.09, 0.09, 
0.2, 0.39, 0.03, 0.09, 0.27, 0.05), G2 = c(0.69, 0.88, 0.31, 
0.54, NA, 0.44, 0.39, 1.25, 0.36, 0.36, 0.26, 0.8, 0.28, 
0.76, 0.76, 0.45, 0.35, 0.42, 0.23, 0.44, 0.55, 0.76, 0.69, 
0.97, 0.68, 0.87, 0.56, 0.99, 0.7, 0.47, 0.72, 0.94, 0.67, 
0.87, 0.63, 0.94, 0.72, 0.72, 0.69, 1.34, 0.58, 0.94, 0.7, 
1.16, 0.94, 0.87, 0.82, 1.14, 1.05, 0.63, 0.97, 0.6, 1.09, 
0.6, 0.59, 0.82, 0.85, 0.68, 0.94, 0.3, 0.31, 0.42, 0.25, 
NA, 0.39, 0.41, 0.5, 0.16, 0.29, 0.25, 0.29, 0.45, 0.35, 
0.39, 0.11, 0.18, 0.38, 0.21), BA2 = c(1.97, 1.76, 1.88, 
2.14, NA, 1.54, 1.72, 1.39, 1.69, 2.45, 1.94, 1.93, 1.14, 
0.56, 2.08, 2.07, 1.67, 1.94, 1.56, 1.32, 0.11, 0.23, 0.14, 
0.06, 0.17, 0.29, 0.14, 0.11, 0.16, 0.12, 0.14, 0.07, 0.13, 
0.29, 0.13, 0.07, 0.07, 0.14, 0.14, 0.2, 0.36, 0.38, 0.29, 
0.54, 0.33, 0.33, 0.35, 0.4, 0.38, 0.35, 0.35, 0.24, 0.39, 
0.3, 0.18, 0.33, 0.43, 0.26, 0.38, 4.23, 2.6, 4.66, 3.75, 
NA, 2.76, 4.1, 4.25, 1.71, 2.79, 2.47, 2.46, 2.68, 1.58, 
3.88, 1.39, 2.23, 4.13, 2.14), total2 = c(4.63, 4.85, 3.44, 
4.21, NA, 3.25, 2.89, 3.3, 3.26, 4.61, 3.56, 4.34, 2.13, 
1.46, 4.85, 3.81, 3.2, 3.33, 2.34, 2.86, 3.42, 3.33, 3.26, 
2.84, 2.55, 2.6, 2.58, 2.75, 3.2, 1.47, 2.81, 2.89, 2.81, 
2.49, 2.64, 3.03, 4.4, 2.3, 2.91, 3.55, 1.12, 1.48, 1.14, 
2.19, 1.37, 1.5, 1.32, 1.84, 1.88, 1.01, 1.39, 1.08, 1.64, 
0.94, 0.86, 1.23, 1.37, 1.2, 1.41, 4.83, 3.01, 5.38, 4.16, 
NA, 3.32, 4.86, 5, 1.98, 3.18, 2.74, 2.84, 3.22, 2.13, 4.66, 
1.53, 2.5, 4.78, 2.4), Shoot.bag = c(3.83, 3.89, 3.98, 3.7, 
3.94, 4.41, 4.81, 4.41, 4.13, 4.26, 4.59, 3.78, 3.95, 4.35, 
4.92, 4.15, 4.37, 4.54, 4.91, 4.44, 3.62, 3.7, 4.37, 4.63, 
4.91, 4.21, 4.94, 4.39, 4.27, 4.66, 4.89, 4.77, 4.77, 4.8, 
5.23, 4.74, 4.66, 4.42, 5.09, 4.82, 4.73, 4.62, 4.81, 4.85, 
4.68, 4.85, 4.83, 5.08, 4.87, 4.9, 5.36, 4.54, 5.35, 4.65, 
5.04, 5.05, 5.2, 5.21, 4.61, 4.25, 4.09, 3.76, 4.04, 3.77, 
3.84, 4.28, 4.66, 3.94, 4.21, 4, 4.66, 3.85, 4.32, 4.47, 
4.26, 4.95, 5.06, 4.75), shoot = c(0.37, 0.43, 0.52, 0.33, 
0.48, 0.95, 1.35, 0.95, 0.67, 0.8, 1.13, 0.32, 0.58, 0.98, 
1.46, 0.69, 1, 1.17, 1.45, 0.98, 0.25, 0.24, 0.91, 1.17, 
1.54, 1.01, 1.48, 0.93, 0.9, 1.29, 1.43, 1.31, 1.31, 1.43, 
1.77, 1.28, 1.29, 1.05, 1.63, 1.36, 1.36, 1.16, 1.35, 1.39, 
1.22, 1.39, 1.37, 1.71, 1.67, 1.44, 1.9, 1.08, 1.89, 1.19, 
1.58, 1.68, 2, 1.75, 1.24, 0.88, 0.72, 0.3, 0.58, 0.4, 0.47, 
0.82, 1.2, 0.57, 0.84, 0.54, 1.29, 0.48, 0.95, 1.01, 0.8, 
1.58, 1.6, 1.38), root.bag = c(2.98, 2.99, 2.91, 2.95, 3.16, 
3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3, 2.98, 2.97, 2.98, 3.02, 3.03, 3.17, 
3.14, 2.96, 3.15, 2.93, 3.16, 2.84, 2.98, 3.06, 3.08, 3.03, 
3, 3.06, 3.05, 2.99, 3.01, 3.05, 3.05, 3.08, 3.14, 3.13, 
3.06, 3.01, 3.09, 3.08, 3.04, 3.12, 3.11, 3.24, 3.16, 3.18, 
3.16, 3.1, 3.22, 3.1, 3.08, 3.29, 3, 3.17, 3.04, 3.11, 3.21, 
3.14, 3.04, 3.23, 3.03, 2.97, 2.94, 3, 3, 3.04, 3.04, 3.02, 
3, NA, 3.02, 3.14, 2.98, 3.05, 3.01, 2.88, 2.95, 3.03, 3.04
), root = c(0.11, 0.12, 0.04, 0.08, 0.29, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.15, 0.16, 0.3, 0.27, 0.09, 0.28, 
0.02, 0.29, 0.02, 0.11, 0.19, 0.21, 0.16, 0.13, 0.19, 0.18, 
0.12, 0.14, 0.18, 0.18, 0.21, 0.27, 0.26, 0.19, 0.14, 0.22, 
0.21, 0.17, 0.25, 0.24, 0.37, 0.29, 0.31, 0.29, 0.23, 0.35, 
0.23, 0.21, 0.42, 0.13, 0.3, 0.17, 0.24, 0.34, 0.27, 0.17, 
0.36, 0.16, 0.1, 0.07, 0.13, 0.13, 0.17, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13, 
0.19, 0.15, 0.27, 0.11, 0.18, 0.14, 0.18, 0.08, 0.16, 0.17
), S.R = c(0.229166667, 0.218181818, 0.071428571, 0.195121951, 
0.376623377, 0.128440367, 0.093959732, 0.128440367, 0.1625, 
0.120879121, 0.081300813, 0.255813953, 0.205479452, 0.140350877, 
0.170454545, 0.28125, 0.082568807, 0.193103448, 0.013605442, 
0.228346457, 0.074074074, 0.314285714, 0.172727273, 0.152173913, 
0.094117647, 0.114035088, 0.113772455, 0.162162162, 0.117647059, 
0.097902098, 0.111801242, 0.120805369, 0.138157895, 0.158823529, 
0.128078818, 0.129251701, 0.097902098, 0.173228346, 0.114130435, 
0.111111111, 0.155279503, 0.171428571, 0.215116279, 0.172619048, 
0.202614379, 0.172619048, 0.14375, 0.169902913, 0.121052632, 
0.127272727, 0.181034483, 0.107438017, 0.136986301, 0.125, 
0.131868132, 0.168316832, 0.118942731, 0.088541667, 0.225, 
0.153846154, 0.12195122, 0.189189189, 0.183098592, 0.245283019, 
0.265625, 0.171717172, 0.111111111, 0.185714286, 0.184466019, 
0.217391304, 0.173076923, 0.186440678, 0.159292035, 0.12173913, 
0.183673469, 0.048192771, 0.090909091, 0.109677419), SPAD_17NOV = c(43, 
39.9, 45, 46, 41, 41.3, 43.5, 43.2, 40, 39.6, 42.9, 43.9, 
42.6, 40.3, 38.4, 39.4, 41.6, 38.2, 36.5, 40.4, 42.6, 43.6, 
48, 43.2, 43, 45.3, 45.2, 48.5, 44.2, 46.8, 47.4, 48.7, 47.7, 
47.4, 43.1, 45.7, 43.9, 44.9, 47.9, 43.9, 52, 47.4, 51.2, 
47.4, 44.8, 47.7, 45.2, 44.2, 44.6, 48.1, 41.5, 44.8, 45.3, 
43.3, 46.6, 44.8, 42.1, 40.6, 46.8, 42.5, 46.7, 44.5, 45.3, 
43.9, 42.2, 43.5, 45.9, 41.1, 44.6, 46.7, 45.8, 42.8, 39, 
43.6, 43.4, 38.5, 39.5, 38.2), plant.height = c(60L, 80L, 
90L, 70L, 130L, 120L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 100L, 110L, 110L, 
130L, 160L, 140L, 130L, 160L, 150L, 170L, 190L, 30L, 140L, 
80L, 70L, 150L, 110L, 110L, 90L, 128L, 120L, 110L, 140L, 
120L, 150L, 130L, 120L, 180L, 160L, 150L, 160L, 80L, 110L, 
70L, 120L, 60L, 90L, 90L, 130L, 150L, 90L, 165L, 140L, 140L, 
150L, 130L, 170L, 210L, 200L, 160L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 110L, 
90L, 70L, 90L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 130L, 120L, 120L, 110L, 
140L, 160L, 150L), leaf.discolour.19NOV = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("", " 1 D", "1", "1  D", "2", "D"), class = "factor"), 
deformation.26NOV = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"D", "D (bad) 1", "D 1"), class = "factor"), herb.dmg.30NOV = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "D"), class = "factor"), herb.dmg.11.DEC = c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L), X.plant.pot = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "dead"), class = "factor"), 
nod = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0.5, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
0.5, 2, 0.5, 2, 2), root.dis = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), surface.root = c(2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), big.bag = c(3.37, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
med.bad = c(3.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), small.bag = c(3.46, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 153L, 154L, 156L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I am using this model to create the break point...

```
fit4 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
        data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Seaton Park"),
        start = list(c = 1.5, m = 0.1, bp = 70), na.action = na.omit)
mm4 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(seat$P), length.out = 100))
mm4$shoot <- predict(fit4, newdata = mm4)
```

However I am having trouble with the estimates. I am using 70 for the bp as I have already calculated it but cant get the c and m to fit. Can you please offer any help?

Comment: The published plot does not appear to be an analysis of data: the points instead appear to be specific locations along a set of given graphs.  Without a doubt the actual data did not all fall on those graphs.

Comment: Is that because all the points fall exactly on the line?

Comment: The output lists `bp`, presumably for "breakpoint".  I might call this "critical x value".  The code you list is for the y value at the breakpoint.  I might call this the "plateau value".

Comment: Pairwise comparisons for what?

Comment: Pairwise comparisons of the critical value for each cultivar. The critical value is the intersection of the regression line for the first four values, and the horizontal line from the last point. The last point represent maximum growth. So the critical value is the amount of P needed to achieve maximum growth. The x value for the break point 'bp' is the 'critical value'

Comment: It would also be good to do pairwise comparisons for maximum growth.

Comment: The x value of the break point is the `bp` parameter: `coef(fit1)[["bp"]]`

Comment: The reasons we can be certain these points are artificial, and are not the data, are (1) the broken-stick model is not biologically plausible; it is a simple mathematical approximation; and (2) it would be astronomically unlikely for so many independent data points to fall perfectly on the fitted curves. (I am referring to the graphic you originally posted, not to the new one in the edited question.)

Comment: So why do you think they presented an artificial graph like that rather than one of the actual data?

Comment: Perhaps try the `segmented` r-package?

Comment: In some package in R there is a function that returns confidence intervals for nls parameters.  You can look to see if confidence intervals for the critical x parameter don't overlap.

Comment: Okay.  What I was thinking of is in the package `nlstools` and the functions `confint2` and `nlsBoot`.

Comment: As to @whuber 's about the artificial nature of these models, sometimes a quadratic-plateau model is used, which is similar in spirit, but makes a little more sense as a biological response.  One practical consideration here is that the linear-plateau and quadratic-plateau models will give different critical x values.  If we have enough data, sometimes we use a Cate-Nelson approach and set the plateau value to something that we are actually interested in, say 90% of maximum crop yield.

Comment: I tried fitting a Michaelis-Menten curve, however there probably isnt enough data points to give accurate predictions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59659297/ The other option I have seen is this 'broken stick' method, which might give more reliable estimates for the given data.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do this for one cultivar:

```
plot(shoot ~ P, data = subset(DF, cultivar == "Dinninup"))
```

[image: resulting plot illustrating relationship between "shoot" and "P"]

```
fit1 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
            data = subset(DF, cultivar == "Dinninup"),
            start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25), na.action = na.omit)
summary(fit1)
#Formula: shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c)
#
#Parameters:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#c   0.831689   0.105243   7.903 4.31e-07 ***
#m   0.033129   0.005829   5.684 2.69e-05 ***
#bp 24.700463   2.193671  11.260 2.65e-09 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.106 on 17 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.205e-08

curve(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(P = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: plot illustrating the fit]

```
#calculate k:
coef(fit1)[["c"]] + coef(fit1)[["m"]] * coef(fit1)[["bp"]]
#[1] 1.65
```

You can then create a combined model using the approach from my answer to your question at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59677502/1412059

The model might be sensitive to starting values (in particular for the break point). You should take care and fit the model repeatedly with slightly different starting values.

Comment: Btw., I assume you have a fully randomized experimental design. If that's not the case (for example if you have a block design), you'd probably need a nonlinear mixed-effects model.

Comment: yes it has four reps, each one a block. So you are saying that it needs to be included as a random effect?

Comment: You need to consider this, yes.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I have updated the post with your advice, though I don't understand how to implement the ANOVA and pairwise comparisons from where I am up to.

Comment: Study my Stack Overflow answer. The approach is exactly the same.

Comment: I have tried to follow your stack overflow post, and added the attempt in the above post. However, I get the following error message for the gnls models: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: The error is because you pass data from only one cultivar to the function and then ask it to stratify by cultivar,

Comment: ah of course. When I try to stratify by cultivar, I now get this error message: "Error in gnls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), data = isosub,  : 
  starting values for parameters are not of the correct length" Starting values are not something I am very familiar with....

Comment: Yes, starting values are a bit difficult. You need to understand treatment contrasts to determine the correct number of starting values. And even if you understand them perfectly, it is sometimes easier to use trial and error. Basically, for each parameter of the non-linear model that is stratified, you have an intercept (reference group) and the differences to this intercept for all other groups. For unstratified parameters you have only one starting value.

Comment: Can you please explain with some example?

Comment: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html

Comment: Could you please advise on how to go about estimating different starting values? For example: c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 25      I can estimate the bp, however, what does the "c" and "m" stand for?

Comment: I have added some info in the question above....

Answer (score 6):

The package `mcp` was made just for scenarios like this. See below how I structured your data as `df` later.

## Fit a change point model

First, let's define a slope followed by a joined plateau. We add varying (random) change point locations (the left-hand side of the equation):

```
model = list(
  shoot ~ 1 + P,  # intercept and slope
  1 + (1|cultivar) ~ 0  # joined plateau
)
```

Now we fit the model with default priors:

```
library(mcp)
fit = mcp(model, data = df, iter = 5000)
```

## Inspect the fit

Let's inspect the full fit for each `cultivar`:

```
plot(fit, facet_by = "cultivar", cp_dens = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can see raw parameter estimates using `summary(fit)` and the corresponding `plot_pars(fit)` (population-level). To focus on the varying change points (i.e., how each `cultivar` group deviates from the population-level change point (`cp_1`)), do `ranef(fit)` and `plot_pars(fit, "varying")`.

[image]

## Testing

Here are two ideas how to test hypotheses. If you want to test whether a given change point occurs later than another, do this to obtain Bayes Factors:

```
hypothesis(fit, "`cp_1_cultivar[Dinninup]` < `cp_1_cultivar[Yarloop]`")
```

I get a BF of around 16 for this one. If you want to test whether a varying change point improves predictive performance in general, fit a null model and use cross-validation:

```
model_null = list(shoot ~ 1 + P, ~ 0)
fit_null = fit = mcp(model, data = df, iter = 5000)

# Leave-one-out cross-validation
fit$loo = loo(fit)
fit_null$loo = loo(fit_null)
loo::loo_compare(fit$loo, fit_null$loo)
```

You can read about `mcp` on [the mcp website](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/) and the underlying models in [the associated preprint](https://osf.io/fzqxv/).

Perhaps it would be appropriate to use an informative prior that the first slope is positive.

## Data

I removed cases with `NA` values, and put the rest in a data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(
  P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
        18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
        12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 
        18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
        48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 
        18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 
        48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
        18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 
        48.35, 48.35, 48.35),
  shoot = c(1.24, 1.12, 1.28, 1.28, 1.37,
            1.4, 1.39, 1.34, 1.34, 1.53, 1.25, 1.4, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.71, 
            1.52, 1.75, 1.63, 1.7, 1.23, 1.22, 1.26, 0.89, 1.2, 1.55, 1.4, 
            1.19, 1.75, 1.92, 1.63, 1.64, 1.34, 1.54, 1.66, 1.88, 1.9, 2.18, 
            2.03, 1.68, 0.9, 1.49, 1.41, 1.57, 0.94, 1.83, 1.6, NA, 1.98, 
            2.04, 1.64, 1.71, 1.97, 1.97, 1.87, 2.21, 2.1, 2.25, 2.1, 2.24, 
            1.23, 1.32, 1.47, 1.54, 1.38, 1.09, 1.41, NA, 1.23, 1.14, 1.63, 
            1.61, 1.42, 1.12, 1.74, 1.89, 1.4, 1.58, 1.71, 1.64),
  cultivar = rep(c("Dinninup", "Yarloop", "Riverina", "Seaton"), each = 20)
)

df = df[complete.cases(df),]
```