# Estimating the starting values in a broken stick regression

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to use the following data and code to create a broken stick linear regression model, however, I am unable to get the starting values right to make it work. I have already calculated the bp, so that shouldn't be the issue, so its the c and m values I am having trouble with. Can anyone please offer some advice on how we can create these values?

```
structure(list(pot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 140L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Seaton 
Park", 
"Dinninup", "Yarloop", "Riverina"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = 
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Non- 
waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35
), form = c(1.65, 0.61, 0.47, 0.57, 0.52, 0.61, 0.48, 0.8, 0.69, 
0.63, 0.39, 0.68, 0.66, 0.51, 0.4, 0.55, 0.45, 0.41, 0.47, 0.54, 
1.7, 1.78, 1.6, 2.34, 1.52, 1.88, 1.67, 1.7, 1.88, 1.59, 1.97, 
1.6, 1.97, 2.13, 1.52, 2.5, 1.88, 1.61, 1.61, 1.65, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.02, 0.05, 0.31, 0, 0.07, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 
0, 0.03, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.12, 0.1, 0.13, 0.05, 
0.07, 0.06, 0.09, 0.05, 0.12, 0.05, 0.1, 0.06, 0.05, 0.06), G = c(0.4, 
0.23, 0.19, 0.12, 0.26, 0.25, 0.19, 0.23, 0.25, 0.4, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.39, 0.38, 0.21, 0.22, 0.28, 0.28, 0.25, 0.28, 1.02, 0.67, 0.8, 
0.78, 0.76, 0.66, 0.79, 0.81, 0.94, 0.61, 0.74, 0.64, 0.99, 0.85, 
0.86, 1, 0.86, 0.75, 0.91, 0.66, 0.91, 0.42, 0.43, 1.02, 1.48, 
0.53, 0.89, 0.7, 0.59, 0.61, 0.42, 1.04, 0.75, 0.59, 0.52, 0.84, 
0.43, 0.53, 0.66, 0.35, 0.19, 0.31, 0.21, 0.27, 0.25, 0.31, 0.21, 
0.28, 0.1, 0.29, 0.09, 0.27, 0.2, 0.19, 0.21, 0.24, 0.11, 0), 
BA = c(1.61, 1.17, 0.94, 0.98, 1.25, 1.27, 1.15, 1.31, 1.23, 
1.42, 0.91, 1.25, 1.43, 1.61, 1.07, 1.32, 1.48, 1.38, 1.25, 
1.48, 0.09, 0.19, 0.2, 0.16, 0.1, 0.19, 0.13, 0.21, 0.14, 
0.16, 0.2, 0.14, 0.2, 0.21, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.16, 
0.17, 0.23, 0.1, 0.21, 0.27, 0.35, 0.1, 0.31, 0.29, 0.32, 
0.14, 0.21, 0.36, 0.38, 0.16, 0.31, 0.32, 0.21, 0.12, 0.33, 
3.49, 2.53, 2.34, 2.5, 3.54, 2.76, 1.56, 3.13, 2.63, 1.48, 
1.58, 2.34, 2.68, 2.96, 1.31, 3.54, 2.18, 1.5, 1.17), total = c(3.66, 
2.02, 1.59, 1.67, 2.03, 2.13, 1.83, 2.34, 2.17, 2.44, 1.49, 
2.19, 2.48, 2.49, 1.69, 2.1, 2.22, 2.07, 1.97, 2.3, 2.81, 
2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 2.95, 2.36, 2.91, 
2.38, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 3.71, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 1.19, 
0.57, 0.66, 1.34, 2.14, 0.63, 1.27, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 
1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.16, 0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 3.88, 2.79, 
2.73, 2.77, 3.86, 3.13, 1.97, 3.46, 2.95, 1.65, 1.94, 2.53, 
3, 3.28, 1.55, 3.85, 2.48, 1.66, 1.23), F2 = c(1.97, 2.21, 
1.25, 1.53, NA, 1.27, 0.78, 0.66, 1.21, 1.8, 1.36, 1.61, 
0.71, 0.14, 2.01, 1.29, 1.18, 0.97, 0.55, 1.1, 2.76, 2.34, 
2.43, 1.81, 1.7, 1.44, 1.88, 1.65, 2.34, 0.88, 1.95, 1.88, 
2.01, 1.33, 1.88, 2.02, 3.61, 1.44, 2.08, 2.01, 0.18, 0.16, 
0.15, 0.49, 0.1, 0.3, 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.03, 0.07, 0.24, 
0.16, 0.04, 0.09, 0.08, 0.09, 0.26, 0.09, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.16, NA, 0.17, 0.35, 0.25, 0.11, 0.1, 0.02, 0.09, 0.09, 
0.2, 0.39, 0.03, 0.09, 0.27, 0.05), G2 = c(0.69, 0.88, 0.31, 
0.54, NA, 0.44, 0.39, 1.25, 0.36, 0.36, 0.26, 0.8, 0.28, 
0.76, 0.76, 0.45, 0.35, 0.42, 0.23, 0.44, 0.55, 0.76, 0.69, 
0.97, 0.68, 0.87, 0.56, 0.99, 0.7, 0.47, 0.72, 0.94, 0.67, 
0.87, 0.63, 0.94, 0.72, 0.72, 0.69, 1.34, 0.58, 0.94, 0.7, 
1.16, 0.94, 0.87, 0.82, 1.14, 1.05, 0.63, 0.97, 0.6, 1.09, 
0.6, 0.59, 0.82, 0.85, 0.68, 0.94, 0.3, 0.31, 0.42, 0.25, 
NA, 0.39, 0.41, 0.5, 0.16, 0.29, 0.25, 0.29, 0.45, 0.35, 
 0.39, 0.11, 0.18, 0.38, 0.21), BA2 = c(1.97, 1.76, 1.88, 
2.14, NA, 1.54, 1.72, 1.39, 1.69, 2.45, 1.94, 1.93, 1.14, 
0.56, 2.08, 2.07, 1.67, 1.94, 1.56, 1.32, 0.11, 0.23, 0.14, 
0.06, 0.17, 0.29, 0.14, 0.11, 0.16, 0.12, 0.14, 0.07, 0.13, 
0.29, 0.13, 0.07, 0.07, 0.14, 0.14, 0.2, 0.36, 0.38, 0.29, 
0.54, 0.33, 0.33, 0.35, 0.4, 0.38, 0.35, 0.35, 0.24, 0.39, 
  0.3, 0.18, 0.33, 0.43, 0.26, 0.38, 4.23, 2.6, 4.66, 3.75, 
NA, 2.76, 4.1, 4.25, 1.71, 2.79, 2.47, 2.46, 2.68, 1.58, 
3.88, 1.39, 2.23, 4.13, 2.14), total2 = c(4.63, 4.85, 3.44, 
4.21, NA, 3.25, 2.89, 3.3, 3.26, 4.61, 3.56, 4.34, 2.13, 
1.46, 4.85, 3.81, 3.2, 3.33, 2.34, 2.86, 3.42, 3.33, 3.26, 
2.84, 2.55, 2.6, 2.58, 2.75, 3.2, 1.47, 2.81, 2.89, 2.81, 
2.49, 2.64, 3.03, 4.4, 2.3, 2.91, 3.55, 1.12, 1.48, 1.14, 
2.19, 1.37, 1.5, 1.32, 1.84, 1.88, 1.01, 1.39, 1.08, 1.64, 
0.94, 0.86, 1.23, 1.37, 1.2, 1.41, 4.83, 3.01, 5.38, 4.16, 
NA, 3.32, 4.86, 5, 1.98, 3.18, 2.74, 2.84, 3.22, 2.13, 4.66, 
1.53, 2.5, 4.78, 2.4), Shoot.bag = c(3.83, 3.89, 3.98, 3.7, 
3.94, 4.41, 4.81, 4.41, 4.13, 4.26, 4.59, 3.78, 3.95, 4.35, 
4.92, 4.15, 4.37, 4.54, 4.91, 4.44, 3.62, 3.7, 4.37, 4.63, 
4.91, 4.21, 4.94, 4.39, 4.27, 4.66, 4.89, 4.77, 4.77, 4.8, 
5.23, 4.74, 4.66, 4.42, 5.09, 4.82, 4.73, 4.62, 4.81, 4.85, 
4.68, 4.85, 4.83, 5.08, 4.87, 4.9, 5.36, 4.54, 5.35, 4.65, 
5.04, 5.05, 5.2, 5.21, 4.61, 4.25, 4.09, 3.76, 4.04, 3.77, 
3.84, 4.28, 4.66, 3.94, 4.21, 4, 4.66, 3.85, 4.32, 4.47, 
4.26, 4.95, 5.06, 4.75), shoot = c(0.37, 0.43, 0.52, 0.33, 
0.48, 0.95, 1.35, 0.95, 0.67, 0.8, 1.13, 0.32, 0.58, 0.98, 
1.46, 0.69, 1, 1.17, 1.45, 0.98, 0.25, 0.24, 0.91, 1.17, 
1.54, 1.01, 1.48, 0.93, 0.9, 1.29, 1.43, 1.31, 1.31, 1.43, 
1.77, 1.28, 1.29, 1.05, 1.63, 1.36, 1.36, 1.16, 1.35, 1.39, 
1.22, 1.39, 1.37, 1.71, 1.67, 1.44, 1.9, 1.08, 1.89, 1.19, 
1.58, 1.68, 2, 1.75, 1.24, 0.88, 0.72, 0.3, 0.58, 0.4, 0.47, 
0.82, 1.2, 0.57, 0.84, 0.54, 1.29, 0.48, 0.95, 1.01, 0.8, 
1.58, 1.6, 1.38), root.bag = c(2.98, 2.99, 2.91, 2.95, 3.16, 
3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3, 2.98, 2.97, 2.98, 3.02, 3.03, 3.17, 
3.14, 2.96, 3.15, 2.93, 3.16, 2.84, 2.98, 3.06, 3.08, 3.03, 
3, 3.06, 3.05, 2.99, 3.01, 3.05, 3.05, 3.08, 3.14, 3.13, 
3.06, 3.01, 3.09, 3.08, 3.04, 3.12, 3.11, 3.24, 3.16, 3.18, 
3.16, 3.1, 3.22, 3.1, 3.08, 3.29, 3, 3.17, 3.04, 3.11, 3.21, 
3.14, 3.04, 3.23, 3.03, 2.97, 2.94, 3, 3, 3.04, 3.04, 3.02, 
3, NA, 3.02, 3.14, 2.98, 3.05, 3.01, 2.88, 2.95, 3.03, 3.04
), root = c(0.11, 0.12, 0.04, 0.08, 0.29, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.15, 0.16, 0.3, 0.27, 0.09, 0.28, 
0.02, 0.29, 0.02, 0.11, 0.19, 0.21, 0.16, 0.13, 0.19, 0.18, 
0.12, 0.14, 0.18, 0.18, 0.21, 0.27, 0.26, 0.19, 0.14, 0.22, 
0.21, 0.17, 0.25, 0.24, 0.37, 0.29, 0.31, 0.29, 0.23, 0.35, 
0.23, 0.21, 0.42, 0.13, 0.3, 0.17, 0.24, 0.34, 0.27, 0.17, 
0.36, 0.16, 0.1, 0.07, 0.13, 0.13, 0.17, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13, 
0.19, 0.15, 0.27, 0.11, 0.18, 0.14, 0.18, 0.08, 0.16, 0.17
), S.R = c(0.229166667, 0.218181818, 0.071428571, 0.195121951, 
0.376623377, 0.128440367, 0.093959732, 0.128440367, 0.1625, 
0.120879121, 0.081300813, 0.255813953, 0.205479452, 0.140350877, 
0.170454545, 0.28125, 0.082568807, 0.193103448, 0.013605442, 
0.228346457, 0.074074074, 0.314285714, 0.172727273, 0.152173913, 
0.094117647, 0.114035088, 0.113772455, 0.162162162, 0.117647059, 
0.097902098, 0.111801242, 0.120805369, 0.138157895, 0.158823529, 
0.128078818, 0.129251701, 0.097902098, 0.173228346, 0.114130435, 
0.111111111, 0.155279503, 0.171428571, 0.215116279, 0.172619048, 
0.202614379, 0.172619048, 0.14375, 0.169902913, 0.121052632, 
0.127272727, 0.181034483, 0.107438017, 0.136986301, 0.125, 
0.131868132, 0.168316832, 0.118942731, 0.088541667, 0.225, 
0.153846154, 0.12195122, 0.189189189, 0.183098592, 0.245283019, 
0.265625, 0.171717172, 0.111111111, 0.185714286, 0.184466019, 
0.217391304, 0.173076923, 0.186440678, 0.159292035, 0.12173913, 
0.183673469, 0.048192771, 0.090909091, 0.109677419), SPAD_17NOV = c(43, 
39.9, 45, 46, 41, 41.3, 43.5, 43.2, 40, 39.6, 42.9, 43.9, 
42.6, 40.3, 38.4, 39.4, 41.6, 38.2, 36.5, 40.4, 42.6, 43.6, 
48, 43.2, 43, 45.3, 45.2, 48.5, 44.2, 46.8, 47.4, 48.7, 47.7, 
47.4, 43.1, 45.7, 43.9, 44.9, 47.9, 43.9, 52, 47.4, 51.2, 
47.4, 44.8, 47.7, 45.2, 44.2, 44.6, 48.1, 41.5, 44.8, 45.3, 
43.3, 46.6, 44.8, 42.1, 40.6, 46.8, 42.5, 46.7, 44.5, 45.3, 
43.9, 42.2, 43.5, 45.9, 41.1, 44.6, 46.7, 45.8, 42.8, 39, 
43.6, 43.4, 38.5, 39.5, 38.2), plant.height = c(60L, 80L, 
90L, 70L, 130L, 120L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 100L, 110L, 110L, 
130L, 160L, 140L, 130L, 160L, 150L, 170L, 190L, 30L, 140L, 
80L, 70L, 150L, 110L, 110L, 90L, 128L, 120L, 110L, 140L, 
120L, 150L, 130L, 120L, 180L, 160L, 150L, 160L, 80L, 110L, 
70L, 120L, 60L, 90L, 90L, 130L, 150L, 90L, 165L, 140L, 140L, 
150L, 130L, 170L, 210L, 200L, 160L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 110L, 
90L, 70L, 90L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 130L, 120L, 120L, 110L, 
140L, 160L, 150L), leaf.discolour.19NOV = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("", " 1 D", "1", "1  D", "2", "D"), class = "factor"), 
deformation.26NOV = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"D", "D (bad) 1", "D 1"), class = "factor"), herb.dmg.30NOV = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "D"), class = "factor"), herb.dmg.11.DEC = c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L), X.plant.pot = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "dead"), class = "factor"), 
nod = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0.5, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
0.5, 2, 0.5, 2, 2), root.dis = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), surface.root = c(2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), big.bag = c(3.37, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
med.bad = c(3.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), small.bag = c(3.46, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 153L, 154L, 156L), class = "data.frame")



fit4 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
        data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Seaton Park"),
        start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 70), na.action = na.omit)
```

Here is the plot I am trying to create. "fit4" is the broken stick for "Seaton Park" Its the last one I need to fit.

[image: Desired plot]

Here is a rough example of what 'fit4' should look like on our plot. The bp is 70 which I calculated using the equations of the lines. It falls beyond our data set, so how can we draw in the broken stick lines without our model?

[image: rough example]

Comment: Your example needs to start with `isosub = structure(....` to be complete.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444527/how-to-do-broken-stick-linear-regression-in-r

Comment: A bit off topic of the question, but a couple of things you might add to help interpretation of these models.  1) Confidence intervals for the critical x values.  The *nlstools* package has functions *confint2* and *nlsBoot* to find the confidence intervals for parameter estimates by profile, asymptotic, or bootstrap approach.  2) pseudo r-squared value.  There are a few that might be applicable, but I think Efron's pseudo r-square is easy to interpret and makes sense for these models.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that good starting values won't help you with that particular data set.  What you can do is set the value of `bp` and then perform the fit.  Then choose the value of `bp` that minimizes the root mean square error.

```
d <- subset(isosub, cultivar=="Seaton Park")
bp <- NULL
sigma <- NULL
for (i in 0:100) {
  bp[i+1] <- 20 + 40*i/100
  bbpp <- bp[i+1]
  fit4 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bbpp, m * P + c, m * bbpp + c), 
        data = subset(isosub, cultivar=="Seaton Park"), 
        start = list(c = 0.33, m = 0.024), na.action = na.omit)
  sigma[i+1] <- summary(fit4)$sigma
}

plot(bp, sigma)
```

[image: Root mean square error for various values of bp]

So `bp` can be set to any value as large as your largest value of `P` and the minimum root mean square error will be achieved.  In other words, for this data set, there is no evidence that a broken stick model is necessary or appropriate.

The figure below shows how the root mean square error keeps getting smaller until `bp` reaches the maximum value of the data set.

[image: Animation of choice of bp and resulting root mean square error]

Comment: Thank you for your time and support JimB. I need this model to work for my current project though.      fit4 <- nls(shoot ~ ifelse(P < bp, m * P + c, m * bp + c), 
        data = subset(isosub, cultivar == "Seaton Park"),
        start = list(c = 1, m = 0.05, bp = 70), na.action = na.omit)

Comment: I should of mentioned more detail. This questions builds on a previous one I asked some time ago which might explain why I need it. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/444867/269996

Comment: To quote Scotty "Cap'n! You can't change the laws of physics!".  For that particular data set the value(s) of `bp` that minimize the variance are beyond the maximum `P`.  Not much you can do about that.  (I understand that you need an answer but you can't get a desirable answer with this data set.)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So if you're a Bayesian, then maybe you can get around the laws of Frequentist physics.

Comment: Well im not expecting to bend the laws of physics. But some sort of advice on how to make the example plot I have just added into the question, "work", would be magic enough in itself.

Comment: I was attempting some humor earlier and maybe my conclusion did not convince you.  If you are picking the values of `bp` and `c` and `m`, then the value of `bp` that minimizes the root mean square error (which is the loss function used by `nls`), then you'll get a value of `bp` outside of your data for Seaton Park.  But not so for the other data sets.  Now...is there some (justifiable) reason why `bp` is the same for all data sets?  If so, you can perform a simultaneous fit to find the common value of `bp`.  But short of that there's nothing other than a Bayesian approach to do.

Comment: bp isnt the same for all data sets. bp is the intersect between the horizontal line (which represents maximum growth i.e. the last point on the right) and the linear response to phosphorus (P) (i.e. the first 4 points). All I need is the picture, so I just need to draw the line just I have done with the other cultivars (Yarloop, Dinninup, Riverina). Ideally I would run pair wise comparisons on the break points (bp) but I cant figure out how to do that. So the picture showing how I calculated bp is sufficient for now.

Comment: Maybe another way to state it, For Seaton Park, the data show no evidence of a plateau in yield, so no critical P value can be calculated.  Or maybe, so the critical P is >= 50 mg/kg.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Agreed.  There is no evidence of a plateau starting below P = 50 mg/kg and the OP (or their supervisor/major professor) doesn't like that result.  Maybe constructing a confidence interval might be more acceptable?  But one shouldn't choose an approach that depends on matching the desired results.

Comment: @SalMangiafico.  Ooops!  I just read your comment to the OP.  You're way ahead of me about the confidence interval approach.

Comment: Adding confidence intervals won't find a plateau for Seaton Park, but it does suggest that the critical x is determined to a reasonably useful precision for Yarloop and Dinninup (95% CI is, say, from 15 to 23, and from 10 to 34, respectively).   On the other hand, the 95% CI for the critical x for Riverina is incredibly wide, and exceeds the maximum x value †.  This suggests that while the linear-plateau (broken-stick) model was able to be fit, we have little confidence that there is a real plateau in these data for Riverina. /// † Depending on the method, but bootstrap failed here.

Comment: @SalMangiafico.  Good points.  The failure of the bootstrap in that instance for Riverina  (and for the basic use of `nls` with Seaton Park)  is probably due to the small number of data points and poor data structure:  there is a huge gap (i.e., lack of data) in P mg/kg soil values between 24 and 50.  And maybe more importantly, here is another case where consulting with a statistician prior to collecting the data and after would be helpful (not that I know that this didn't happen).  Not everyone with a computer should be analyzing data.